# how to split datetime in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime, split

I am getting data as datetime format here is the format

```
10/10/1991 12:00:00 AM
```

I want only date

```
10/10/1991
```

So how can I split this

I am using this code to bind the data

```
  $scope.Customer.CU_DOB = data.cU_DOB.
```

where

```
data.cU_DOB=10/10/1991 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: `cU_DOB.split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use angular's [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

```
var date = new Date('10/10/1991 12:00:00 AM');

$scope.formatted = $filter('date')(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9fd0xdg/)

Comment: Best answer because it also preserves the information that the data is in *datetime* format and doesn't just handle the data as a generic string.

Comment: great answer ndoes

Answer (score 1):

You can try spliting the string based on spaces

```
var cU_DOB="10/10/1991 12:00:00 AM"
var date = cU_DOB.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  
  $scope.Customer={CU_DOB: "10/10/1991 12:00:00 AM"};
var splitarray = new Array();
splitarray= $scope.Customer.CU_DOB.split(" ");

var date = splitarray[0];

alert( date );
});

</script>
</html>
```